# Copy current value of another cell dynamically

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have a row `A2:D2` as in the image:

[image: screen shot]

Column `C` represents *Gold Price* of this day. Coulmn `A` represents the date.

Cell `F2` represents the *Current Gold Price*.

`C` cells formula: `=F$2`.

When I drag the row down I get `A3:Z3`:

[image: screen shot]

If the price changes at `F2` then the `C` column will change showing the new value of `F2`.

I want to automatically copy the current value of `F2` and insert it in the dragged cells CN.

Comment: Can you share a sheet? The way your asking the question, its unclear what you expect the end result to be

Comment: The last result should be like this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQOp1ftjL9ak1n9NAEZmoMMa9frurb3rBAeqkxO5qCI/edit?usp=sharing

note: the F2 is imported form another sheet

Comment: Are you copying and pasting the other data  as well - or are columns A,B,and D also automatically inserted into the sheet?

Comment: No, I shouldn't copy anything, only B column is editable,

users should drag the row to generate new row with the current gold price every day

Comment: the price (D Column) should be fix and persistent forever

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your questions correctly, you want to be able to change the value in `F2` but keep a history of that value in the 'C` column. All this, while all other cells update automatically by dragging down the cells.
In that case, I don't know a possible way.

What you could do is to not get the `C` column value from the "*Current Gold Price*" value in the `F2` cell, but perhaps have it pulled directly from the source. It depends on how your source is. If that is a column that gets updated based on the date then use it as a reference just as you are doing with `F2`.

Comment: Thank you, that exactly what I want, but unfortunately, the source updates the cell every while, not adding new cell :(

Comment: Is the source only one cell that gets updated manually? Not a column?

Comment: Yes only one cell